# Angularjs angular-ui-ace editor tab key not working and misspelled options

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

Issues:

1. When I set ace editor to html mode the tab key no longer tabs.
2. When I try and set options I get the following error message/s

misspelled option "enableLiveAutocompletion"

misspelled option "enableEmmet"

My bower.json looks like this

```
{
    "name": "fountain-inject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.1.0",
        "angular": "^1.5.0",
        "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
        "angular-dragula": "^1.2.7",
        "medium-editor": "^5.21.0",
        "angular-ui-ace": "bower"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "ace-builds": {
            "main": ["src-noconflict/ace.js",
                "src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js",
                "src-noconflict/theme-monokai.js",
                "src-noconflict/mode-html.js",
                "src-noconflict/ext-emmet.js"
            ]

        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "angular-mocks": "^1.5.0"
        }
    }
}
```

and my code looks like this

```
_editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
_editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
_editor.getSession().setOptions({
    "enableBasicAutocompletion": true,
    "enableSnippets": true,
    "enableLiveAutocompletion": false,
    "enableEmmet": true
});
```

And my html (which is a 'view')

```
<div class='parent' ng-controller='Main'>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='container' dragula='"fifth-bag"'>
        <div data-type="a">A</div>
        <div data-type="b">B</div>
        <div data-type="c">C</div>
    </div>
    <div id="dragulaCopyWithSort" class='container' dragula='"fifth-bag"'>
    </div>
    <div ui-ace="{ 
    onLoad: aceLoaded,
    onChange: aceChanged
    }">ace</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how does your html look? misspelled option means that `ext-language_tools.js` have not been loaded

Comment: how do you include the scripts?

Comment: Using gulp to process the bower.json file.

Comment: the most probable place of the error is in the way you load scripts, please try to create a demo or make the app private, so that someone can help you to find the bug.